# Esconder Teclado ao enviar mensagem

Tags: android, android-layout

Olá, então.. estou procurando uma solução para quando o usuario enviar a mensagem o teclado fechar automaticamente.Agradeço desde já.

```
<Button

    android:id="@+id/singleComentBtn"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btnchat"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/singleBlogComent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/retangulo"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/singleComentBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/singleComentBtn"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/singleComentBtn"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente é isso que você procura, esse trecho de código força o Android a ocultar o teclado,

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Dessa maneira dependendo da ocasião pode acontecer com que o teclado fique oculto sem você querer, sendo assim, você pode substituir o segundo parâmetro do método `hideSoftInputFromWindow` por  `InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY`

Fonte:[Hide Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: não está esta funcionando

Comment: é só colocar na atividade e pronto?